# Resolving Azure subdomain.MyName.cloudapp.net on the internet

Tags: domain-name-system, azure

I would like to add several subdomains to my **Azure** site.
The subdomains should be visible on the Internet (browsable).

Port 80 is open.
MyName.cloudapp.net opens without issues outside of the server and resolves to correct IP address with nslookup and ping (ping times out but that's an Azure thing, it's fine).

All subdomains (sub1.MyName.cloudapp.net, sub2.MyName.cloudapp.net, etc.) **resolve correctly** on the machine itself, but outside they give an error:
*app-1626259443ec0b.MyName.cloudapp.net’s server DNS address could not be found.*
Ping request cannot find the host.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I am aware, you cannot add subdomains to the default cloudapp.net domains you get from Azure. If you want to do this you will need to bring your own custom domain and setup DNS records appropriately.

Setting up an Azure DNS zone for for myname.cloudapp.net is not going to do you any good as your not delegated to administer that DNS.

Comment: You might be right. The DNS zone I set up yesterday is still not working. What is bugging me though is that I saw a deployment where non-custom subdomains were somehow working. What possible workarounds they used (other than editing host files on local computer) I can't fathom but I will be trying to find out or guess.

Comment: You were right. I have to use a custom domain and in that custom domain's DNS provider set redirection. All is working for me now. Thank you very much for help.